# fstream c++ error

Tags: c++, fstream

Tengo este trozo de codigo,

```
void saveGame(vector<Usuario *> vector) {
    fstream file_obj;
    file_obj.open("users.dat");
    for(Usuario *u: vector){
        string auxName,auxPassword;
        auxName = u->getName();
        auxPassword = u->getPassword();
        //file_obj << auxName +" "+auxPassword;
        file_obj << "Hola";
    }
    file_obj.close();
}
```

El tema es que no me graba nada en el archivo, he probado comentando i escribiendo el "hola" pero tampoco lo pone.
Alguien puede echarme un cable?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te faltaría indicar que el `fstream` se abre para salida

2 opciones:

- usando `ofstream`
- usando `fstream` con el flag `out`

`savefile.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  ofstream archivo;
  archivo.open("salida.txt");
  archivo<<"hola"<<std::endl;
  archivo.close();

  fstream otroArchivo;
  otroArchivo.open("salida2.txt", ios::out);
  otroArchivo<<"Hola! 2"<<std::endl;
  otroArchivo.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!